# Error: "Trying to get property 'resource' of non-object" al usar paginate()

Tags: laravel, json, api

Estoy practicando como hacer una API con LARAVEL 7 y me quedé trancado en querer generar un ResourceCollection para enviar un JSON.

Me sale el siguiente error en el **POSTMAN**:

> "Trying to get property 'resource' of non-object"

Esto es lo que tengo en mi Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::paginate(9);

    if($request->wantsJson()){
        return new ProductsCollection($products);
    }

    return view('products.index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Y eso es lo que tengo en mi Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($element){
            return [
                'id' => $element->id,
                'title' => $element->name,
                'description' => $element->description,
                'price' => $element->price,
                'image' => $element->image_url
            ];
        })
    ];
}
```

El error se elimina al cambiar **paginate()** por **all()**, ¿Alguna forma de lograrlo en esta versión de Laravel? Busqué en la documentación y no veo ayuda y en el curso que estoy viendo no hay problema con ese código (aunque es una version de Laravel más vieja)

Comment: Prueba  con `'data' => $this->collectResource($this->collection)->transform(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como el señor **porlocerros** dijo en su comentario. La solución es cambiar

```
$this->collection->
```

por

```
$this->collectResource($this->collection)->
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La explicación a que eso funcione, sería que "Transformamos la colección de modelos en una colección de recursos.". No sé exactamente que versión de Laravel 7.x estás usando, pero según Taylor Otwell, fué arreglado en la versión 7.8. No lo había probado, simplemente lo tomé de este hilo [Breaking change in ResourceCollection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32513)